# JFrame window resizing on every compile. Different results every time

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Erm, I'm not too sure what's happening... For the life of me I didn't even try and debug after running the application several times in a row from the IDE. I decided to come straight over here and explain what I consider to be odd.

I'm trying to create a chessboard with tan and beige squares, I have a JFrame window set to 1024x1024 in size, so a square. I also am using a gridLayout of 8x8.

Every time I run the application I might get a grid of say 6x8, the next run a 5 x8, or next a 7x7.

Not sure what's going on... Any help would be sweet!

```
public class ChessBoard extends JFrame{

private final JFrame board = new JFrame();
private final JButton button = new JButton();
private final GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(8, 8);

public ChessBoard(){
    board.setSize(1024, 1024);
    board.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    board.setVisible(true);
    board.setLayout(grid);
    AddGridColors();
}

private void AddGridColors(){
    Color tanColor = new Color(210, 180, 140);
    Color beigeColor = new Color(245, 245, 220);

    JPanel[] panelArray = new JPanel[63];

    int panelArrayIndex;
    for(panelArrayIndex = 0; panelArrayIndex < 63; ++panelArrayIndex){
        panelArray[panelArrayIndex] = new JPanel();

        if(panelArrayIndex == 0){
            panelArray[panelArrayIndex].setBackground(tanColor);//tan
            panelArray[panelArrayIndex].add(new JLabel("square"+panelArrayIndex));
            board.add(panelArray[panelArrayIndex]);
        }
        if(panelArrayIndex > 0){
            if(panelArrayIndex % 8 == 0){
                panelArray[panelArrayIndex].setBackground(beigeColor);
                panelArray[panelArrayIndex].add(new JLabel("square"+panelArrayIndex));
                board.add(panelArray[panelArrayIndex]);         
            }
            if(panelArray[panelArrayIndex-1].getBackground().equals(tanColor)){
                panelArray[panelArrayIndex].setBackground(beigeColor);
                panelArray[panelArrayIndex].add(new JLabel("square"+panelArrayIndex));
                board.add(panelArray[panelArrayIndex]);
            }else{
                panelArray[panelArrayIndex].setBackground(tanColor);
                panelArray[panelArrayIndex].add(new JLabel("square"+panelArrayIndex));
                board.add(panelArray[panelArrayIndex]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this normal, am I missing something incredibly obvious?

Comment: "*For the life of me **I didn't even try and debug** after running the application several times in a row from the IDE. I decided to come straight over here and explain what I consider to be odd.*" - Not cool.. Go debug. Asking for debugging help is actually considered off-topic here. We aren't a bug hunting service - that's what debuggers are for.

Comment: Could you try moving the call to `AddGridColors();` right before `setSize(1024, 1024);`? If that helps, let me know so I can explain what's happening. Also, shouldn't your for-loop be from 0 to 64 instead of 0 to 63?

Comment: Also `public class ChessBoard extends JFrame{` and `private final JFrame board = new JFrame();` don't make sense, you are extending `JFrame` without any reason.

Comment: That does work, cheers!

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right, Ansharja. I'm not sure why I had written that.

Comment: I thought the first index of an array was 0. So up to 63 would be a total of 64 index's... Ahhh. I see what you're getting at.

Comment: The array size of `panelArray` is 63, which means the highest index is 62. Not sure where you're all getting 64 from. 0 to 64 would be 65 indexes, which should throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my above comment:

> Could you try moving the call to `AddGridColors();` right before `setSize(1024, 1024);`

This could be because you're calling `setVisible(true);` before you've added all your elements to the `JFrame` and thus, causing issues like this one.

`setVisible(true);` should be the last line on your program.

Btw follow the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

- `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`
- `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`
- `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`
- `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`

I said this:

> Also, shouldn't your for-loop be from 0 to 64 instead of 0 to 63?

Because your for-loop is going from `0-63` (without including `63`)

```
for(panelArrayIndex = 0; panelArrayIndex < 63; ++panelArrayIndex){
```

Should be either:

```
for(panelArrayIndex = 0; panelArrayIndex < 64; ++panelArrayIndex){
```

Or

```
for(panelArrayIndex = 0; panelArrayIndex <= 63; ++panelArrayIndex){
```

But the same should go for your panel's array (There are 63 elements, not 64):

```
JPanel[] panelArray = new JPanel[63];
```

Should be:

```
JPanel[] panelArray = new JPanel[64];
```

Comment: Cheers for all your help!

Comment: If this answer solved your question, please be sure to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so other people know this question is already solved.

Comment: Hmmm, I have more questions, but enough for now.

Comment: When you have more questions, ask them as a new post. You should ask one question per post